# Present SKScene from UIViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, skscene, presentviewcontroller

I would like to make a game using a UIViewController for the Menu and a SKScene for the GameScene.

When the player press the Play button on the Menu, I would like a transition between the Menu and the GameScene with something like :

```
let nextScene = GameViewController()
self.presentViewController(nextScene, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I got this error :

`Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x19ff623e0) to 'SKView' (0x19f813e70).`

How can I do this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code inside of `GameViewController` is trying to treat `self.view` as a `SKView` but its actually a `UIView`.

You will either need to set the views class to `SKView` in the storyboard/xib or create it yourself in your view controllers `loadView` method.

Comment: The problem is that I don't use storyboards, I make all the menu programmatically

Comment: How can I set the views class to SKView in loadView ? I'm sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: You just need something like `self.view = SKView()`